# How to Create an CommonsMultipartFile instance

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I try to create CommonsMultipartFile instance by this way，but a java.lang.NullPointerException happened.

```
 DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(1024*1024,null);
 FileItem fileitem = factory.createItem("file", "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8", true, "d:\\a.xls");//Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.toString()
    CommonsMultipartFile commonFile=new CommonsMultipartFile(fileitem);
```

Comment: You shouldn't create it yourself. Why would you need this?

Comment: Yes，I shouldn't create it by myself.And the reson of ‘java.lang.NullPointerException’ is no OutputStream get."fileitem.getOutputStream();"solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `null` as the second parameter to the constructor.

Pass some sort of temp folder like so:

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(1024*1024, Files.createTempDirectory("mytemp").toFile());
```